# Options DIV Inside Jquery Dialog Top Fixed Position

Tags: css, jquery-ui, position

I have a Jquery Dialog. Inside the dialog i have a DIV with a "Save Button". This DIV can have multiple buttons or dropdowns depending on the scenario. So it's actually a TOP Options Div.

Image Here:

[image]

I need to have this DIV always VISIBLE. Right now If the dialog content exceeds the dialog height then If I scroll down I lose the visibility of my options div.

Any clue on how to perform this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put the rest of the dialog content into a div, to which you apply a fixed height and an overflow-y: scroll attribute.

```
height : 250px
overflow-y: scroll
```

So in fact it's not the whole dialog you will scroll up and down while the top div stays fixed, but the second div content while the top div just stays at its place.

Example : [dialog with fixed top and scrolling content](http://jsfiddle.net/NorthernWill/2TckJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/andromedado/Gq54S/

The assumption is that wrap around the "New User", "close", scrollable content and buttons pane is already position fixed.

From there, you just have to make the buttons pane also position fixed, and give it the appropriate width so that it doesn't overlap the scrollbars.
Finagling width vs. padding can be verbose, so I cheated in the script and just declared vars to hold the padding info.

I also added an element "buttonSpacer", which gets it's height from the floating buttons pane; this gives the floating content something to push against, so it doesn't end up underneath the buttons pane.